# preg_replace, regex getting Text Parts

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have the following problem:

I have a Text with the e.g. the following Format:

```
min: 34.0 max: 79.0383 lifetime: 17% code:iweo7373333
```

It's not a fixed text Type, means min can also be `-7.94884444` or so. How can i extract the parts in e.g. an array like

```
$result['min'] = 34.0;
$result['max'] = 79.0383
and so on...
```

I did it at the moment with replacing spaces, then replace "min:" with nothing, "max:", "lifetime:", ... with "," and then an explode... The main Problem is that sometimes other variables are between min, max, .... so the positions do not hold the correct values.

Also - i think - it's not a really good coding style or? Is this possible with regex or preg_replace?

Thanks,
Sascha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Also - i think - it's not a really good coding style or?

There is no need to be authoritative about it. It depends on your purposes. I would personally opt for JSON in this case. XML can be an overkill most of the times.
The only advantage I see in keeping that format you proposed is that it has no need for complex syntax using `{}()[];,` (and it seems you don't need nesting).

This regex will match all the `parameter:value` combinations from your string, being very tolerant with use of whitespace on values:

`(?<=^| )[A-Za-z-_]{0,}:[.,\$\-\+\s%\w]{0,}(?<=\s|\Z|^)`

So in PHP:

```
$string = "simple:I like to exchange data a-css-like-parameter: 34px CamelCasedParameter: -79.0383 underlined_parameter: 17%";

preg_match_all('/(?<=^| )[A-Za-z-_]{0,}:[.,\$\-\+\s%\w]{0,}(?<=\s|\Z|^)/', $string, $matches);

$parameters = array();
foreach($matches[0] as $parameter){
    $exploded = explode(':', $parameter);
    $parameters[$exploded[0]] = trim($exploded[1]);
}

print_r($parameters);
```

Output:

```
> Array
> (
>    [simple] => I like to exchange data
>    [a-css-like-parameter] => 34px
>    [CamelCasedParameter] => -79.0383
>    [underlined_parameter] => 17%
> )
```

Comment: this works best for me thanks. ok, thanks. first i have to say, that i perhaps have used the wrong words. it's for me not a good coding style i mean. i like using easy ways if possible :) the next thing is, i cannot define the format i get this connect - else i of course prefer JSON.

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing "bad" about using preg_replace or regex. It's certainly not ideal to be parsing this unformatted string, though. If you can modify the source string, try [JSON](http://json.org) or XML for more reliable results. At the very least, even a url format would work better (e.g. min=123&max=456&limit=789).

Now on to the main question:

```
// test data
$result = array('min' => false, 'max' => false, 'lifetime' => false);

// match any occurence of min/max/lifetime followed by : followed by text (anything not a space)
if( preg_match_all('/\b(min|max|lifetime): +([^ ]+)/', $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER) ) {
   foreach($matches as $m) {
      $result[$m[1]] = $m[2]; // put each match into $result
   }
}
var_dump($result); // see what we got back
```

Comment: ok, thanks. first i have to say, that i perhaps have used the wrong words. it's for me not a good coding style i mean. i like using easy ways if possible :) the next thing is, i cannot define the format i get this connect - else i of course prefer JSON.